# Android Switched Startup Activity: Old Startup Activity still behaves as such

Tags: android, navigation, android-activity, back-button

Very strange thing here.

I initially had an activity that was the start up activity (Activity A). It had the tag `android:launchMode="singleTask"` associated with it. No problems. My requirements changed and now i'm making Activity B the startup activity. I copied the intent filter over, I changed the name to ".ActivityB" and I moved the launch mode tag over as well.

It seems to work okay; when I start the app I go to Activity B. However when I go from Activity B to Activity A and then click the back button the app exits and won't reopen (it will reopen if I don't have the launch mode tag.)

Another example. If I go from Activity A to Activity B to Activity A to Activity B everything is fine. When I click back i go to Activity A (as expected) however when I click back again I go to a previous instance of Activity A (uh oh) then I click back again and exit the app. Both times skipping Activity B.

I'm clearly overlooking something but I can't figure out what. I'm not overriding any back button functionality and everything worked perfectly before I switched the start up activity.

**Edit**
The following is an excerpt from my manifest before any change

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityA" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ActivityB"></activity>
```

Here is an excerpt after the change

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ActivityA"></activity>
```

Comment: Did you copy or _move_ the intent filter? Not sure what will happen if you have 2 activities with a launch intent filter on em

Comment: No, please see the edit, Also I've heard you can actually have two activities declared to be a startup activity (maybe I heard wrong). I'm not sure what that does..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Activity B is getting `finish()` called or something. I suggest putting in some log statements in `OnCreate`, `OnPause`, `OnResume`, and `OnDestroy` so you can monitor the life of Activity B. Its a highlander activity (there can only be 1) so you don't have to worry about multiple instances being created. Also you might look into / override [`onNewIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) and placing some logging calls there.

Not really an answer, but dollars to donuts you or someone put a `finish()` call after starting Activity A, or when Activity B goes in the background and you've forgotten about it.

If that's not the case I'd be interested in how/when Activity B dies. Usually if it stops because of some error upon returning to it, Android will bark at you but since you didn't mention that I'd guess it isn't.

Comment: If I could send you donuts I would. You were dead on with that last addition. Originally I was _finishing_ Activity B when it went back to Activity A (the home activity) because Activity B was no longer needed for anything so I figured I'd just finish it and free some resources.

Comment: I'd prefer the dollars actually :D